# How to get text from programmatically created EditText in an Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, textview

I have an application where EditTexts are created programmatically at start. Lets say it creates 4 EditTexts and these are added in the TableLayout. I create it with this line (it is in a for loop):

`newEditText = new EditText(this);`

It is created fine. The problem is, when i set an "setOnKeyListener", it does not work. It simply cannot detect if the key is pressed. Here's a simple part of the code:

```
    public void populateUIOnStartup() {

        lastRow = sharedPreferencesForLastRowCount.getInt("schoolPlaceIndex", 0);


        for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount <= lastRow; rowCount++) {
            final TableLayout tableLayout = findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            row.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            final TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParamsForEditTextScale = new TableRow.LayoutParams(10, 10);

            final String schoolPlace = sharedPreferencesForschoolPlaces.getString("schoolPlace" + rowCount, null);

            if (schoolPlace != null) {

                List<EditText> allEDs = new ArrayList<EditText>();

                schoolPlaceEditText = new EditText(this);
                schoolPlaceEditText.setTag(schoolPlace + "schoolNumber");
                schoolPlaceEditText.setId(rowCount);
                schoolPlaceEditText.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsForEditTextScale);
                schoolPlaceEditText.getLayoutParams().height = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.editText_height);
                schoolPlaceEditText.getLayoutParams().width = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.editText_width);
                schoolPlaceEditText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
                schoolPlaceEditText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);


                schoolPlaceEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


                    String exactschoolPlaceEditText = schoolPlaceEditText.getTag().toString();

                    EditText schoolNumber = tableLayout.findViewWithTag(schoolPlace + "schoolNumber");
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


                        Log.i(schoolPlaceEditText.getTag().toString(), s.toString());

                        try {
                            schoolPlaceEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                                    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == event.KEYCODE_ENTER && s != null && Double.valueOf(s.toString()) != 0) {
                                        double school_number = 0;
                                         try {
                                            school_number = Double.valueOf(s.toString());
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                        return true;
                                    } else {
                                        schoolPlaceEditText.setText("");
                                    }
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    }
                });



                row.addView(schoolPlaceEditText, new TableRow.LayoutParams((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.editText_width), TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        tableLayout.addView(row, rowCount);

            }
        }

    }
```

Here, the first "log" outputs things correctly. But the second "log" (Test2) outputs nothing. What can be wrong?

Comment: Did you put an id to edittext, because setOnKeyListener is looking for something. I don't know how to pass the id to the editext programatically. So try to debug your app or see carefully your logcat what is saying, to know what is wrong.

Comment: Yes I added an ID. But it is not "mentioned" anywhere. What can I do next?

Comment: Well, you dindn't added so much information. Please add some more code, to see what can I do to help you.

Comment: I edited the original post, and added the full function. Thanks

Comment: did you chekced the logcat

Comment: Yes, no errors.